# Shortcuts for git commands

Tags: git

I would like to use shortcuts or aliases for git commands.

```
git diff
git status
git push 
git pull
git stash
git branch -a
```

How do I create shortcuts or aliases, is there a predefined list?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Put this into your `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
  st = status
  ci = commit
  br = branch
  co = checkout
```

You can add as much as you want

Comment: Is there a list of the most commonly used ones somewhere?

Comment: It is up to you. You can alias your favourite git commands or the ones that you use frequently

Comment: .gitconfig file location : https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Where-system-global-and-local-Windows-Git-config-files-are-saved

Comment: This can also be done via the `git` command line, without manually editing the .gitconfig file (local or global), as Fred Foo's answer below demonstrates.

Answer (score 28):

```
git config --global alias.<short> <long>
```

e.g.

```
git config --global alias.cob "checkout -b"
```

(Without `--global`, you get per-project aliases.)

Comment: For reference: [Git Aliases Documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

Answer (score 28):

I would recommend [oh-my-zsh git](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh) shortcuts.

It has a very thorough (more than 100 shortcuts) list.

Here is a **small** sample to get you started:

```
alias ga='git add'
alias gc='git commit -v'
alias gd='git diff'
alias gst='git status'

alias gco='git checkout'
alias gcm='git checkout master'

alias gb='git branch'
# view remote branches
alias gbr='git branch --remote'

alias gup='git pull --rebase'
alias gp='git push'
# push a newly created local branch to origin
alias gpsup='git push --set-upstream origin $(git_current_branch)'
```

The selection of letters in most shortcuts make them adequately intuitive.

Using the shortcuts provided by a popular and active open source project has many benefits. Some of which:

- never care if you lose them since you can easily find them!
- increases the chances of other people having the same shortcuts as you and thus learn from each other.
- decreases the chances of shortcuts conflicting with other commands.

Even if you don't use zsh, you can still **copy** them in a regular shell configuration file like `.bashrc`.

I have also added

```
alias oh='less ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh'
```

so that I can quickly read the available shortcuts right from the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

More than one way to do this. Explained below with examples:

**[1] Using the "alias" option provided by the git itself.**

**Example:** git config --global alias.co checkout

**Usage hence:** git co

This is equivalent to making entries manually in the *'~/.gitconfig'* (this path since, *--global* is used, otherwise the *.gitconfig* file of the project, in which you attempting to set will be used).

```
[alias]
  co = checkout
```

Therefore, manually making entry to the file, as specified can also be another way of setting your aliases.

[for more Info](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

**[2] Using .bash_profile/.bashrc.**

Edit your *~/.bash_profile* or *~/.bashrc*, as below:

**Example:** alias go='git checkout'

**Usage hence:** go

(Do not forget to 'source ~/.bash_profile' or 'source ~/.bashrc' after the changes to the file, based on your case).

[for more Info](https://jonsuh.com/blog/git-command-line-shortcuts/)

So, if you clearly see, the second way is to further put the shorthand/aliases to the git-command usage (for your profile).

Also, the aliases meant for ease of usability, hence what you prefer/at ease, is what you can add (like: i can say probably, Giraffe = git checkout, if that is my ease).

Answer (score 0):

I made a terminal "Mode" for bash called `git_mode` in order to avoid typing `git` and use `c` for `commit` and so forth.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/Tredecies/git_mode).

Sample commands look like:

```
# Add
alias a='git add'
alias add='git add'

# Diff
alias d='git diff'
alias diff='git diff'

# Grep/Search
alias search='git grep'
alias grep='git grep'

# Merge
alias merge='git merge'
alias m='git merge'

# Branch
alias b='git branch'

# Status
alias s='git status'
alias status='git status'

# Commit
alias c='git commit'
alias commit='git commit'

# Remote
alias remote='git remote'

# Pull
alias pull='git pull'

# Push
alias push='git push'

# init
alias init='git init'
alias i='git init'

# clone
alias clone='git clone'

# checkout
alias ch='git checkout'
alias checkout='git checkout'

# stash
alias stash='git stash'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [this library, SCM Breeze](https://github.com/scmbreeze/scm_breeze). It gives really cool UI for files and easy to use.