# Git push -u origin <my-current-branch> shortcut

Tags: git, github

I am trying to edit my .gitconfig to add a shortcut that takes into account my current branch and pushes it, even if there is no upstream defined yet.
To reference my current branch I would normally do:

`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`

My problem is that this solution can't be used for shortcuts.

What I want to do is push the current branch and set its upstream branch. Currently I do:

`git push -u origin <my-current-branch>`

And I wanted to make a shortcut like:

`git pu`

How can I add the reference to the current branch in my .gitconfig ?

NOTE: The  can be any branch I am working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default behavior of "git push" without a branch specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified)

Comment: Check this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753603/shortcuts-for-git-commands

Comment: My problem is not creating a shortcut. My problem is referencing the current branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
git config --global alias.pu 'push -u origin HEAD'
```